# Spark: Creating an index using groupByKey to produce sorted, distinct value list?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark to create an "inverted index" that will map an English token back to the documentIds where the token is found. Given existing data of the form:

```
documentId1, token
documentId2, token
```

I would like to create an inverted index of the key, value form:

```
token, List(documentId1, documentId2, documentId3, ...)
```

where the value is a list of documentIds that are  **sorted** and **distinct** (unique).

Here is what I have so far: :

```
// List of (documentId, token) pairs
var data = Array((100, "spark"), (50, "spark"), (50, "spark"), (1, "apache"), (3, "apache"), (2, "apache"))
var myrdd = sc.parallelize(data)
var myrddGrouped = myrdd.map(pair => (pair._2, pair._1)).groupByKey()
// myrddGrouped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])] = ShuffledRDD[226] at groupByKey at <console>:31

myrddGrouped.foreach(println)
// (apache,CompactBuffer(1, 3, 2))
// (spark,CompactBuffer(100, 50, 50))
```

As you can see, I am using groupByKey(), but the result value is a CompactBuffer, not a List. How can I apply "distinct" and "sort" to it?

Comment: ```myrddGrouped.mapValues(_.toSeq.distinct.sorted)```

Comment: Instead of `myrdd.map(pair => (pair._2, pair._1))` you can simply use the `swap` method of `Tuple2`'s: `myrdd.map( _.swap )`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend aggregating into a set instead of using `groupByKey`. This way duplicates will be eliminated during aggregation and then you can convert to some sort of `List` and apply your sort.

Using some of the suggestions in the comments, perhaps something like the following should work:

```
val input = sc.parallelize(Array((100, "spark"), (50, "spark"), (50, "spark"), (1, "apache"), (3, "apache"), (2, "apache")))
val setRDD = input.map(_.swap).aggregateByKey(Set[Int]())(_ ++ Set(_), _ ++ _)
val sortedListRDD = setRDD.mapValues(_.toList.sorted)

** sortedListRDD.foreach(println)
** (spark,List(50, 100))
** (apache,List(1, 2, 3))
```

A small note is that you should declare your RDD's as `val` since they are immutable. It is possible to reassign a `var` with a new RDD but since you don't seem to be doing that, I would just use `val`'s.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = Array((100, "spark"), (50, "spark"), (50, "spark"), (1, "apache"), (3, "apache"), (2, "apache"))
var myrdd = sc.parallelize(data)
var myrddGrouped = myrdd.map(pair => (pair._2, pair._1)).groupByKey().mapValues(_.toSet.toList).collect

res141: Array[(String, List[Int])] = Array((spark,List(50, 100)), (apache,List(1, 2, 3)))
```